Abhidharma dharmas compared with Kantian categories
I have been reading SEP articles in alphabetical order and came across a very interesting article on the school of Abhidharma.
According to the texts, it splits sentient experience into many categories in which, supposedly, everything experiential can be classified within or from the relationship between the categories.
I thought that this was very similar to the Kantian categories, in practically every way except for the fact that Abhidarma has a lot more categories than Kant ever proposed.
Is there any major difference between the Abhidarma categories and the Kantian ones, outside of just number? I am particularly wondering if the Abhidarma categories suffer from the same deficiencies that Kant's does, or if it suffers from different ones when classifying experience.
Also, if there are any references for further readings feel free to link or suggest them if it is related to Abhidarma or Abhidarma in relation to Kant.

These are ancient texts you're consulting (cogito). Prepare to have your mind blown if prescience is your thing. I haven't read Abhidharma, but I do know that the Hindus studied rationalism and empricism (Kant's project), admitting them as 2 modes of knowledge.

i dont know anything about indian philosophies, but a read almost everything written by schopenhauer and his whole philosophical project was about unifying kant and buddhism
